# RestKit mapping for org.joda.time.Interval obj

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit, jodatime, httpresponse

I have working part for mapping simple JSON response. Here how it look like:

```
RKObjectMapping *eventMapping = [Event responseMapping];
RKResponseDescriptor *listEventsResponseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:listEventsResponseDescriptor];
```

And of course Event class (DTO)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface Event : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *image;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) responseMapping;

@end

@implementation Event

+ (NSDictionary *) elementToPropertyMappings {
    return @{
             @"id": @"id",
             @"title": @"title",
             @"detail": @"detail",
             @"image": @"image",
             };
}

+ (RKObjectMapping *) responseMapping {
    // Create an object mapping.
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Event class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[Event elementToPropertyMappings]];

    return mapping;
}

@end
```

So, this way allows me working with next response (processed field in the bottom of the server response):

```
(
        {
        dateInterval =         {
            afterNow = 0;
            beforeNow = 1;
            chronology =             {
                zone =                 {
                    fixed = 0;
                    id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    uncachedZone =                     {
                        cachable = 1;
                        fixed = 0;
                        id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    };
                };
            };
            end =             {
                afterNow = 0;
                beforeNow = 1;
                centuryOfEra = 20;
                chronology =                 {
                    zone =                     {
                        fixed = 0;
                        id = "Europe/Kiev";
                        uncachedZone =                         {
                            cachable = 1;
                            fixed = 0;
                            id = "Europe/Kiev";
                        };
                    };
                };
                dayOfMonth = 12;
                dayOfWeek = 4;
                dayOfYear = 71;
                equalNow = 0;
                era = 1;
                hourOfDay = 13;
                millis = 1426160220000;
                millisOfDay = 49020000;
                millisOfSecond = 0;
                minuteOfDay = 817;
                minuteOfHour = 37;
                monthOfYear = 3;
                secondOfDay = 49020;
                secondOfMinute = 0;
                weekOfWeekyear = 11;
                weekyear = 2015;
                year = 2015;
                yearOfCentury = 15;
                yearOfEra = 2015;
                zone =                 {
                    fixed = 0;
                    id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    uncachedZone =                     {
                        cachable = 1;
                        fixed = 0;
                        id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    };
                };
            };
            endMillis = 1426160220000;
            start =             {
                afterNow = 0;
                beforeNow = 1;
                centuryOfEra = 20;
                chronology =                 {
                    zone =                     {
                        fixed = 0;
                        id = "Europe/Kiev";
                        uncachedZone =                         {
                            cachable = 1;
                            fixed = 0;
                            id = "Europe/Kiev";
                        };
                    };
                };
                dayOfMonth = 12;
                dayOfWeek = 4;
                dayOfYear = 71;
                equalNow = 0;
                era = 1;
                hourOfDay = 13;
                millis = 1426160160000;
                millisOfDay = 48960000;
                millisOfSecond = 0;
                minuteOfDay = 816;
                minuteOfHour = 36;
                monthOfYear = 3;
                secondOfDay = 48960;
                secondOfMinute = 0;
                weekOfWeekyear = 11;
                weekyear = 2015;
                year = 2015;
                yearOfCentury = 15;
                yearOfEra = 2015;
                zone =                 {
                    fixed = 0;
                    id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    uncachedZone =                     {
                        cachable = 1;
                        fixed = 0;
                        id = "Europe/Kiev";
                    };
                };
            };
            startMillis = 1426160160000;
        };
        detail = "\"I know you cannot count beyond ten, so I will tell you. Hold up your  two hands. On both of them you have altogether ten fingers and thumbs.  Very well. I now take this grain of sand&mdash;you hold it, Hoo-Hoo.\" He  dropped the grain of sand into the lad's";
        id = 14;
        image = "6f655fd8-ac0d-454f-8b8d-5c93eab34030.png";
        new = 0;
        title = "I know you";
    },
        { ...
```

Most of the server's response regarding date interval. This JSON created Java Spring, on the field JodaTime Interval.

**Question:** How can I get two NSDate property fields from this JSON?

Comment: Due to the fact that I do not know how to map shown JSON - I decided to change the task. So now I have a response that removed question.
        ( {
        detail = "\"I know you cannot count ...";
        id = 14;
        image = "6f655fd8-ac0d-454f-8b8d-5c93eab34030.png";
        new = 0;
        title = "I know you";
        endDate = "10/02/2015 17:07";
        startDate = "10/02/2015 17:06";
        },
        { ...

Comment: Your modified JSON is the preferred approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class `MyRestKitJodaTimeModel` (or a number of classes) that matches the JSON structure and you can use RestKit for it. Then use the data (you could use the milliseconds) and create an `NSDate` from it.

```
NSDate datefromJSON = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)[myRestKitJodaTimeModel millis]/1000]];
```

With `MyRestKitJodaTimeModel myRestKitJodaTimeModel` containing that data from your JSON.

This assumes that you have good reasons for using RestKit, such as lots of other classes that match well. On the other hand, If is is the only data that you receive than using RestKit would make your life more difficult than easier.

Comment: I didn't think about mapping hierarchies of objects because there too much work. Was hope for some magic that will do itself. In this task I understood that I need correct way to to serialize object at server side. Something like [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda). In another task with higher priority (when the server can't touched) I go your way. Thanks